# validate each of has many through on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following models:

```
class Parcel < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :items
  has_many :custom_declarations, :through => :items

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items


  validates :custom_declarations, :presence => true , :on => :update, :if => :parcel_requested

  def parcel_requested
    status_changed?(from: nil, to:'REQUESTED')
  end



class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :parcel, optional: true
  has_many :custom_declarations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :custom_declarations,:reject_if => :all_blank 




class CustomDeclaration < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item
```

I am trying to make sure that each Item contained in this parcel has Custom Declarations

so if `Parcel.items.first.custom_declarations.valid?` returns `true`,  the whole parcel becomes valid, even though `Parcel.items.second.custom_declarations` has no value.

it would be much easier if I am checking one item directly /items/1/ but I am checking it through parcel which has_many items , and each item has custom declaration.

is there a built in way in rails to achieve this ?

Comment: What do your other models look like?

Comment: I have updated the code.

Comment: If you add ```has_many :parcels, :through => items``` to your CustomDeclaration model and ```belongs_to :custom_declarations``` to your Item model, you'll be able to call parcel.custom_declarations directly, after you create an instance of parcel.

Comment: thank you for trying to help, I can already call it and it returns a `CollectionProxy` of Custom Declaration for that parcel, but as the question points out. If one item has custom declaration , the validation line passes because `parcel.custom_declarations` has a value. I want to validate that Each Item has custom_declaration when Parcel status changes from `nil` to `REQUESTED` sorry for the caps , this is how I got it defined in the method above.

Comment: Then you can iterate over the CollectionProxy and check each custom_decaration.

Comment: how to iterate over `custom_declarations` for each `parcel.items`  ? that is my question please. not `parcel.custom_declarations` directly.

Comment: You can use the each method. Something like this:
@custom_declarations.each do |cd|
  (your code here)
end
[Here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each) is the documentation.